# Remove empty nodes and also nodes that have empty childs

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to remove empty nodes from the source XML. Removing the empty nodes is already succeeded. But I also try to remove all nodes that contain child nodes that are empty.

**Source XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <element>
        <a></a>
        <b>sde</b>
        <c fixedAttr="fixedValue">
            <d>ert</d>
            <e></e>
        </c>
        <f fixedAttr="fixedValue">
            <g></g>
            <h></h>
            <i></i>
        </f>
    </element>
</data>
```

**Current XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()) and normalize-space()='']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Current result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <element>
        <b>sde</b>
        <c fixedAttr="fixedValue">
            <d>ert</d>
        </c>
        <f fixedAttr="fixedValue"/>
    </element>
</data>
```

**Wanted result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <element>
        <b>sde</b>
        <c fixedAttr="fixedValue">
            <d>ert</d>
        </c>
    </element>
</data>
```

The empty parent node `<f fixedAttr="fixedValue"/>` also needs to get removed.

Comment: It is not completely clear what is to consider as **empty**.  Your xslt looks like empty is if there is no text, child,  attribute etc.  But your node f has an attribute and should be considered as empty any way?

Comment: Indeed attributes can be ignored. If child elements contain no text the parent is considered empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested it very much but following xslt seems to be working.

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:if test="normalize-space(string(.)) != ''">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Edit:
If you wanted preserve empty attributes it could be done with this

```
<xsl:template match="node()[normalize-space(string(.)) != '']|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove nodes which are parent of nodes which are ignored (considered as empty) by your template:

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(@*|* |comment()|processing-instruction()) and normalize-space()='']"/>
```

Add a new template:

```
<xsl:template match="*[ * and not(*[ @* or * or comment() or processing-instruction() or normalize-space()!='']) ]"/>
```

Which only locks for nodes which have children in input but would not have children in output.